# Placing Buttons Dynamically at specific position in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to place several buttons dynamically in `RelativeLayout`. The problem is that all the buttons are placed at the same spot even thought the x and y coordinates are calculated properly. Is it the right way to specify coordinates using `LayoutParams` and setting `marginRight`, `marginBottom`?

Code:

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);

                int currentX = 20;
                int currentY = 20;

                for (Product product: controller.getProducts("pizza")){

                    Log.d(TAG, "CurrentY: " + currentY);
                    Log.d(TAG, "CurrentX: " + currentX);

                    Button tempButton = new Button(getActivity());
                    tempButton.setId(product.getId());
                    tempButton.setText(product.getName());

                    layoutParams.rightMargin = currentX;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = currentY;
                    tempButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    layout.addView(tempButton);

                    if (layout.getWidth() < currentX + MARGIN_LEFT + BUTTON_WIDTH){
                        currentX = 20;
                        currentY += BUTTON_HEIGHT + MARGIN_BOTTOM;
                    }
                    else{
                        currentX += MARGIN_LEFT + BUTTON_WIDTH;
                    }


                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error. It seems like that I have to re-instantiate `LayoutParams` each time it goes through the loop, it is not enough to just set margin attributes while using the same `LayoutParams` instance. I thought that it adds the button to the specified layout immediately after `addView()` method is called, but it actually does it at the end (When the method is finished), because it placed all the buttons to the same (last) coordinates.

Code:

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {

            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

            int currentX = 20;
            int currentY = 20;

            for (Product product: controller.getProducts("pizza")){

                layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);

                Button tempButton = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                tempButton.setId(product.getId());
                tempButton.setText(product.getName());

                layoutParams.setMargins(currentX, currentY, 0, 0);
                tempButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                layout.addView(tempButton);



                if (layout.getWidth() < currentX + MARGIN_LEFT + (2 * BUTTON_WIDTH)){
                    currentX = 20;
                    currentY += BUTTON_HEIGHT + MARGIN_BOTTOM;
                }
                else{
                    currentX += MARGIN_LEFT + BUTTON_WIDTH;
                }


            }

            //layout.requestLayout();

        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i get `BUTTON_WIDTH,BUTTON_HEIGHT ,MARGIN_BOTTOMMARGIN_LEFT`  i am also wnated to place multiple buttons dynamically. Can you please help me. Your code is really helps me alot. Please guide me further . I am new in android.